# Как расположить элементы в std::list, чтобы поиск элемента по значению происходил бы за время, не большее логарифмического?

Tags: c++, база-данных, list, time-complexity

Как организовать расположение элементов в `std::list`, чтобы поиск элемента по значению происходил бы за время, не большее логарифмического в среднем ( amortized O(log(N)) ) ?

Вопрос с собеседования по С++

Подсказка к вопросу: как устроены индексы для поиска записей в БД?

Comment: Никак? Раз нам нужно обходить связный список, то разве мы не упираемся в O(n)?

Comment: Может там `std::vector` упоминался, ане `list`? Где вы такие кривые вопросы все время откапываете?

Comment: Точно помню, что list, а не vector

Comment: В списке это нереально - только если в кч дереве

Comment: В сухом остатке - очевидное решение - отсортированный массив и бинарный поиск (O(logN)) здесь нельзя применить в виду того, что нет дешёвого произвольного доступа. Даже если список отсортирован, вам придётся пройти половину списка, чтобы найти средний элемент, что уже даёт O(n). А если размер списка неизвестен, то список придётся пройти от начала до конца, чтобы понять какого он размера. Поэтому Вас и спрашивают - точно ли там был std::list

Comment: вопрос вывихнутый. По сути дела подсказка говорит об организации дополнительных структур а не о расположении. С тем же успехом можно организовывать карту

Answer (score 0):

Да, без вектора здесь не обойтись, но если вспомнить, что итераторы листа инвалидируются только при удалении элемента из списка, то можно хранить отсортированный список и вектор итераторов этого списка, а поиск осуществлять с помощью std::equal_range в векторе итераторов с перегруженным компаратором. При таком подходе как раз получится амортизированная O(log(N)), то есть при добавлении или удалении из списка придется перестраивать вектор за линейное время. Пример кода:

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::list<int> TIntLst;
    typedef TIntLst::const_iterator TIntLstIndex;

    TIntLst lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9};
    std::vector<TIntLstIndex> vecIndexes;
    for (TIntLstIndex index = lst.begin(); index != lst.end(); ++index)
    {
        vecIndexes.push_back(index);
    }

    int val = 6; // <-- ищем в списке

    auto range = std::equal_range(
        vecIndexes.begin(),
        vecIndexes.end(),
        lst.end(),
        [&val, &lst](TIntLstIndex lhs, TIntLstIndex rhs) -> bool
        {
        if(lhs != lst.end())
        {
            return *lhs < val;
        }
        if (rhs != lst.end())
        {
            return *rhs > val;
        }
        });

    return 0;
}
```